# Python "root" loglevel and levels of other handlers

Tags: python, logging

I have a script where I'm trying to have the option of logging various things (optionally) both to the console and to a logfile. I'd also like to be able to set different log levels for either log destination, i.e. DEBUG to the logfile and INFO to the console.

I have this working already by starting a "root" logger and then optionally creating different handlers for this logger within which I can set the log level independently. However, I am concerned that this requires setting the lowest possible log level to the "root" logger, and even if I don't set any handlers to the low level, that perhaps the system is still going to be bogged down by a large amount of log events.

To clarify, if I set logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING) and then in fileHandler or consoleHandler try to use 'logging.DEBUG', I'll still only get WARNING-level log prints in either one of my log destinations. This makes sense to me as fileHandler and consoleHandler are sub-objects (pardon my lack of proper vocab) to logger, but again, I just want to make sure that having the lowest possible log level to my "root" logger doesn't actually do anything unless a handler is actually set to a low level too.

```
import logging
import logging.handlers

LOG_TO_STDOUT = 1
ENABLE_LOGFILE = 1

logFormatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
### DO NOT CHANGE main logger log level. This sets the lowest log level available for other loggers
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

if ENABLE_LOGFILE == 1:
    fileHandler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler('crisco.log', maxBytes=2000, backupCount = 5)
    fileHandler.setFormatter(logFormatter)

    ### Set logfile log level (DEBUG, INFO, WARNING, ERROR, CRITICAL)
    fileHandler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    logger.addHandler(fileHandler)

if LOG_TO_STDOUT == 1:
    consoleHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
    consoleHandler.setFormatter(logFormatter)

    ### Set console log level (DEBUG, INFO, WARNING, ERROR, CRITICAL)
    consoleHandler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    logger.addHandler(consoleHandler)

logger.info("this message should show both in file and console")
logger.debug("this message should be in the file only")
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "having the lowest possible log level to my "root" logger doesn't actually do anything". It won't log messages anywhere else than in your two handlers, if that's what you fear.

Comment: Yeah, I get that it won't log messages anywhere else, but will I take a hit, performance-wise, for having a root logger set at DEBUG level, even though my console/file handlers are set higher? Or is the actual stdout/write-to-file the actual hit and logging that doesn't go anywhere (like DEBUG messages if both handlers are set to INFO, for example) doesn't really incur much of a penalty?

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#handler-basic)

**Handler**

...

*The setLevel() method, just as in logger objects, specifies the lowest severity that will be dispatched to the appropriate destination. Why are there two setLevel() methods? The level set in the logger determines which severity of messages it will pass to its handlers. The level set in each handler determines which messages that handler will send on.*

Answer (score 2):

*I just want to make sure that having the lowest possible log level to my "root" logger doesn't actually do anything unless a handler is actually set to a low level too.*

That's not the way it works. The logger's log level is the gateway to the handlers and it must be set as low as the lowest handler if you want the handler to receive the message. The logger will hand all messages that pass its log level check to all of its handlers and will let the handlers decide if they take it or not. There is some overhead, but for most programs, its trivial.